# HTML – Show menu on hover

Tags: html, css, menu, mousehover

I want to show a menu when the navigation item is hovered. According to my design, the menu is absolute positioned. I'm using Google Chrome. When I hover over the menu, the menu disappears. How can I achieve my goal?

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7Q7/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="hoverzone"> hover here 

  <ul class="menu">
<li> home </li>
<li> works </li>
<li> contact </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu{
position: absolute;
top: 33px;
display: none;
}

.hoverzone{
position: relative;
}

.hoverzone:hover .menu{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem...the fiddle is working well!

Comment: Works for me too, what browser are you using?

Comment: there must be a problem elsewhere in the html, could you post full page?

Comment: I' using google chrome, whenn I hover over the menu , the menu disappears

Comment: when you try to hover on the menu it disappears.. I guess that's the problem..!!

Comment: oh, I see now, you just need to have the hoverzone extend with the menu

Comment: less the value of class menu from the top http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7Q7/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be the issue of `z-index` try adding `z-index:999` to your menu class.

Comment: It will not work in your fiddle as there are no other elements to show its effects. It may work on the actual site where there will be other layers which might be above the menu layer.

Comment: It will be effective when applied on the actual site. The person is saying that in spite of the correct script he is unable to see his menu on hover. So this was my approach and I am pretty sure that it might work on the actual website.

Comment: Thank you all. I am pleased to help.

Comment: Whilst this may have fixed the OP's problem, this solution doesn't solve the question posed (particularly with reference to the [jsFiddle posted](http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7Q7/1/)).

Answer (score 4):

Because you have positioned `.menu` absolutely, it takes up no space within `.hoverzone`, therefore `.hoverzone`'s height won't expand for `.menu` and the `:hover` state is not activated when hovered over your menu.

**One way** of overcoming this is not to position it absolutely, but relatively instead:

```
.menu{
    position: relative;
    top: 33px;
    display: none;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7Q7/10/)

Comment: Note that although there is no content below the menu in the example fiddle, using `position:relative` here will make the menu remain in 'the flow' thus pushing any content below (eg: http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7Q7/12/)

Comment: I prefer `top: 100%;` so it's independent of the height of the .menu element.

Comment: The specifics are up to the OP. All I've aimed to do is demonstrate why the code isn't working as they are expecting.

Comment: @oGeez Noted. It wasn't a criticism. I still +1'ed you ;)

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to modify your mark up slightly so your hover zone is within your list, this is also better for accessibility.

Like the code below

```
<ul class="hoverzone">
    <li> hover here 

        <ul class="menu">
            <li> home </li>
            <li> works </li>
            <li> contact </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

 </ul>
```

Then some basic css like this will work

```
ul.hoverzone {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position : abolsute;
}



ul.hoverzone li {
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
}

ul.hoverzone li ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10em;
    left: -999em;
}

    ul.hoverzone li:hover ul {
        left: auto;

}
```

An example is here http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7Q7/4/

This method is a basic example of suckerfish menus which have been around for years. See here for more details http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

Answer (score 2):

The fiddle works but when you try to move down to the menu it disappears. This is because `.menu` is 33px away from the .`hoverzone` and your mouse exits `.hoverzone` before entering `.menu`. Simply position the `.menu` within `.hoverzone` and offset it with padding:

```
.menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    padding-top:33px;
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nn7Q7/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can change your css as shown below or you can use jquery for that.....

> .menu{ position: absolute; top: 33px; display: none; }
>
> .hoverzone{ position: relative; height: 300px; }
>
> .hoverzone:hover .menu{
>       display: block; }

Answer (score 0):

I ususally go away from lists, tables, and all that other stuff, because a lot more css is needed at the end to get the styling right. I normally do my dropdown menu's like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="hoverzone"> 
    hover here 
    <div class="subMenu">
        <div class="subMenuItem">
            home
        </div>
        <div class="subMenuItem">
            works
        </div>
        <div class="subMenuItem">
            contact
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hoverzone:hover .subMenu
{
    visibility: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.subMenu
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.subMenuItem:hover 
{
    background: gray;
}
```

But this is all up to you and what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.hoverzone{
      position: relative;
      padding:20px;
      width:100px;
      border:1px solid #ddd;
      transition:all 0.5s linear;
      cursor:pointer;
      background-color:gold;
 }
 .menu{
      left: 0;
      list-style: none outside none;
      padding: 0;
      position:absolute;
      transition:all 0.1s linear;
     z-index:-1;
   }

  .hoverzone:hover .menu{
     margin-top:21px;
     transition:all 0.5s linear;
    }
 .hoverzone:hover .menu li{
     position:relative;
     top:0;
     transition:all 0.5s linear;
   }
.hoverzone .menu li{
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    width: 100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-30px;
    left:-1px;
   }
```